# How to write bash script without using sudo in it?

Tags: bash, shell-script

How can I write a `gem install` or `apt-get install` in `bash` without letting it use `sudo`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update -y
apt-get upgrade -y
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
((EUID)) || exit
gem install jekyll
```

Comment: do you want to prevent a script from being executed as sudo ? or what !

Comment: an single command in it .... prevent gem install to run as sudo

Comment: it is not working.. i did something wrong..

Comment: I don't understand. If you wan a command to not be run with `sudo` _then don't add sudo in front of that command_. Please [edit] your question and clarify what you are trying to do and how it is failing.

Comment: It could be that you want to update your sudoers file to use `NOPASSWD:` option for use with this specific script.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
((!EUID)) && { # check if the EUID is a zero 
  echo "${0##*/} can not be executed as root " # notify
  exit 1 # exist with status code 1
}
gem install jekyll
```

since you are an admin (normal user) the variable $EUID always greater than zero !
  and in root $EUID = 0

((expression))
              The  expression  is evaluated according to the rules described below under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  If the value of the expression is non-zero, the return status is
              0; otherwise the return status is 1.  This is exactly equivalent to let "expression"

### or

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[[ $EUID = 0 ]] && { # check if the EUID is eq to zero
  echo "${0##*/} can not be executed as root " # notify
  exit 1 # exist with status code 1
}
gem install jekyll
```

*i prefer this one*

```
((EUID)) || exit 1
```

or

```
((!EUID)) && exit 1
```

[image]

### updates after question edit

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
((!EUID)) && {
 #stuff to be exec as root
for option in update 'upgrade -y'
  do
    apt-get $option
  done
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm

} || {
 #stuff to be exec as non-root
gem install jekyll

}
exit 0
```

now it will run in both root and non-root users but it will exec only a part of the script according to the EUID

Comment: I m getting an error like 'The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.'

Comment: Won't this solution fail for a logged in `root` user too?